# Выделение запятыми "и это правильно"

Tags: пунктуация

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему в данном контексте "и это правильно" обособляется запятой?

«Ответ "спорт и питание" уже прозвучал, и это правильно».

Comment: Так все-таки "и это правильно" или "и это нормально"? Отредактируйте, пожалуйста, Ваш вопрос.

Comment: Исправил, извиняюсь.